# Change my default browser if it is not present in default applications

Tags: 16.04, system-settings, default-browser

Under Ubuntu 16.04 I needed to install Firefox. I installed it via terminal, but the problem is that I can`t make it default via Default Applications tab because it is just not present there. How is it possible to fix this?

UPD:
My output for

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

is:

```
Selection    Path                           Priority   Status
------------------------------------------------------------

0            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       auto mode

1            /usr/bin/chromium-browser       40        manual mode

* 2            /usr/bin/firefox                40        manual mode

3            /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable   200       manual mode
```

But still links in Skype, for example, opens with Chrome. And Firefox is not listed in default applications

```
UPD2:
```

`update-alternatives --query x-www-browser` gives:

```
Name: x-www-browser

Link: /usr/bin/x-www-browser

Status: manual

Best: /usr/bin/firefox

Value: /usr/bin/firefox

Alternative: /usr/bin/chromium-browser
Priority: 40

Alternative: /usr/bin/firefox
Priority: 200

Alternative: /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
Priority: 30
```

Comment: Firefox is the default browser in Ubuntu. It is also the only web browser preinstalled.

Comment: Not in my case, maybe I have some special edition, it was preinstalled on my Dell laptop

Answer (score 6):

There are a lot of different situations which Ubuntu comes without a browser in them, e.g: minimal installation using network installer.

Make sure "Firefox" is installed:

```
$ dpkg -l firefox | grep ^ii
ii  firefox        53.0.3+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.2
```

If it's not install it:

```
$ sudo apt install firefox -y
```

Set Firefox as your default browser:

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox.desktop
```

If it did not worked follow the bellow instruction:

Give the chrome a lower priority:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-www-browser x-www-browser /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable 30
```

Then use `update-alternative` to make "Firefox" your default browser:

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
```

It will show you available browsers:

```
  1            /usr/bin/chromium-browser   40        manual mode
  2            /usr/bin/firefox            40        manual mode
```

Pick the one you want, in this case 1 or any other you like and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: @wasd  updated the answer ;)

Comment: I set lower priority to google-chrome, but links still are opened with chrome, which is choosen in Default applications and Firefox is not present there, so I can't change it (

Comment: Give firefox a higher priority then, something like 200. see what happens.

Comment: Done, still no changes. Or should I restart laptop?

Comment: No need for restart, add the output of this command to your question: `update-alternatives --query x-www-browser`

Comment: Run this `xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox.desktop`. then check and see if it's working.

Comment: Yes, it does change it to Firefox, the only issue is that it starts new window every time. Is it possible to open window in opened browser?

Comment: It does not related to default application anymore, it might be related to Firefox's "desktop" file I guess. Ask an other question to diagnose this behavior.

Comment: for me `xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox.desktop` was perfect solution, clean, fast, CLI, works in Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

I just use:
`update-alternatives --config x-www-browser`